# What are the alternatives to the Open Source Job Scheduler?

Tags: cron, scheduled-tasks

Are there any alternatives to the [Open Source Job Scheduler](http://jobscheduler.sourceforge.net/osource_scheduler_introduction_en.htm)?
I'm looking for a way to gain more control over scheduled work tasks than plain cron is offering, but haven't found anything else but Quartz, which isn't language-neutral.

Comment: I don't think we have enough information to work with.  Please provide clearer requirements!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's JAMS. http://www.mvpsi.com/JobScheduling.aspx

Especially awesome if you're using OpenVMS

Answer (score 2):

We use JAMS as well but it's not cheap.  When I hear "open source" I think "free" and JAMS is far from free. My boss negotiated the agreement so I don't know all of the gory details but I know we spent in excess of $35,000 for JAMS

By the way, I should mention that it is a great tool and their support is awesome

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure from your question, but I think SuperScheduler could match your requirements: 
http://www.acelet.com/super/SuperScheduler/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine what do you expect from it, if you want "task scheduler" than you probably want to specify interval and task itself. that's exactly what cron is for.

Answer (score 0):

Someone mentioned JAMS on OpenVMS.  We use JAMS on Windows with UNIX and Linux Agents.  They have a Cron converter as well which is not perfect but it does about 90% of the work moving Cron jobs into JAMS. website is jamsscheduler.com and jamssupport.com